# How to compute the differential sum per group of values based on order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an invoice table which contains customers, the products they bought, and the amount of sales.

```
+----------+---------+-------+
| customer | product | sales |
+----------+---------+-------+
| bob      | apple   |    10 |
| john     | apple   |     8 |
| sarah    | apple   |     3 |
| bob      | pear    |    22 |
| glenn    | pear    |    13 |
| tim      | pear    |     8 |
| cody     | pear    |     4 |
+----------+---------+-------+
```

This table would be generated by a query of

```
SELECT customer, product, SUM(sales) 
FROM Invoice 
GROUP BY customer, product 
ORDER BY product, SUM(sales) desc
```

Is it possible to write a query that computes - per product - the sum of the difference in sales between the top customer and the rest? For example, for apple, the value would be 9. `(10 - 8) + (10 - 3) = 9`. For pear, the value would be 41. `(22 - 13) + (22 - 8) + (22-4) = 41`.

This new query would return a result of

```
+---------+-----------+
| product | salesDiff |
+---------+-----------+
| apple   |         9 |
| pear    |        41 |
+---------+-----------+
```

For products that have only 1 customer, i would like the query to return 0 in sales difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Start by determining the max per product. Then sum the difference.

I've included your sample data and added a single customer buying oranges to demonstrate that aspect of the requirement.

```
declare @t table (
    Customer varchar(10),
    Product varchar(10),
    Sales int
)
insert @t
select 'john', 'orange', 10 union all
select 'bob', 'apple', 10 union all
select 'john', 'apple', 8 union all
select 'sarah', 'apple', 3 union all
select 'bob', 'pear', 22 union all
select 'glenn', 'pear', 13 union all
select 'tim', 'pear', 8 union all
select 'cody', 'pear', 4

;with MaxSalesPerProduct as (
    select MAX(Sales) ms, Product
    from    @t t
    group by t.Product
)
select  t.Product, SUM(ms.ms - t.Sales)
from    @t t
        inner join MaxSalesPerProduct ms on
            ms.Product = t.Product
group by t.Product
```

Note that no special handling of the 'top customer' is needed because the difference there cancels out to 0.

---

**Addendum**

While my original answer works with the sample data you provided, it does assume only a single row per customer+product combination. If this is not the case, then you'll need to adjust the query to take that into consideration.

```
;with SalesPerCustomer as (
    select SUM(Sales) CustomerSales, t.Product, t.Customer
    from    @t t
    group by t.Product, t.Customer
), SaleStats as (
    select  spc.Product, MAX(spc.CustomerSales) MaxSales, COUNT(*) CustomerCount, SUM(spc.CustomerSales) TotalSales
    from    SalesPerCustomer spc
    group by spc.Product
)
select  *, MaxSales*CustomerCount - TotalSales as DiffSum
from    SaleStats
```

Comment: Craig, this is working well. Thank you for the addendum, however my use case requires the data to always be grouped by customer and product, so there is only a single row of customer+product. I have another question if you don't mind, if each customer was associated with a "type", say "online","in-store","mail", could i compute the salesDiff PER customer type, and then sum all those to get the same result format?

Comment: @EricGuan Yes it would be possible. Change the MaxSalesPerProduct to MaxSalesPerProductCustType. Then add another CTE to the `WITH` statement calculating SalesDiff per customer type. And finally `SELECT` from that CTE to perform the overall aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your query with one more grouping

```
SELECT product, count(customer)*max(sales) - SUM(sales) as diff
FROM (
    SELECT customer, product, SUM(sales) as sales
    FROM Invoice 
    GROUP BY customer, product 
) t
GROUP BY product 
ORDER BY SUM(sales) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way should be to find max of sum of sales in the same query where you're finding sum of sales and then just sum up the differences by aggregating on product.

Try this:

```
select
    product, sum(max_sales - sales) salesDiff
from (
    SELECT customer, product, SUM(sales) sales, max(SUM(sales)) over (partition by product) max_sales
    FROM Invoice 
    GROUP BY customer, product
) t
group by product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
    create table dbo.Customer_Prod
    (Customer varchar(32),
     Product varchar (32),
     Sales real
     )


insert into dbo.Customer_Prod values ('bob', 'apple', 10), ('john', 'apple', 8),('sarah', 'apple', 3),('bob', 'pear', 22),('glenn', 'pear', 13),('tim', 'pear', 8),('cody', 'pear', 4)


  with max_sales_Per_Product as (
  Select max(Sales) as Max_Sales, product
          from [AtlasDB].[dbo].[Customer_Prod] 
  Group by Product 
  )

  Select sum(B.Max_Sales - (A.sales)) AS Diff_Sales, A.Product 
  from [AtlasDB].[dbo].[Customer_Prod] A LEFT OUTER JOIN
  max_sales_Per_Product B on B.Product=A.Product
  group by A.Product
```

[image]